# How to defer failure from inner function to outer

Tags: functional-programming, language-agnostic, option-type

I have a function `g : (T -> Double) -> T` which expects a function `f : T -> Double`.

However, I don't have a `T -> Double`. I have a function `f_err : T -> Maybe Double` that might fail. I can't modify `g` itself, but is there some way of using `f_err` in `g` (or some wrapper of `g`), such that when `f_err` is successful, using `f_err` with `g` results in a `Just T`, and when `f_err` fails, you get `Nothing` - basically deferring the `Maybe` to the final result, rather than the intermediate result of `f_err`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify `g` to use functors or something else instead?

Comment: @user can you give an example?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what `g` looks like, but if it's something like this `g f = h (f some_t)`, then you might be able to turn that into something like `g f = fmap h (f some_t)`. (Pardon any errors I made here, I'm not a Haskell programmer)